# Mostrar ventana solo una vez al recargar la pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero mostrar un div sola una vez cuando cargue la pagina, pero sigue apareciendo cada vez que recargo la pagina.

```
<div class="Banner-Promo">
   <div id="content-Promo">
      <div id="cerrar-popup">X</div>
         <img src="Banner Domicilio Gratis.png"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
if(!window.sessionStorage.getItem("mostrarModal")){         
     window.sessionStorage.setItem("mostrarModal","no");               
    $('#content-Promo').modal("show");
}
```

de esta manera cuando se carga por primera vez la consola me arroja "true" y "undefined".

```
var viewed = Cookies.get('viewed');

console.log(viewed)

if (viewed == "true") {
  $("#content-Promo").fadeOut();
} else if (viewed == undefined) {
  $("#content-Promo").fadeIn();
  Cookies.set('viewed', true);
}
```